# What does 'Toggle hard wrap on commit' do in Atom?

Tags: git, github, atom-editor, git-commit

Using the Atom editor with a Github repository.

When I type Enter in the commit comment box, a little 'Enter' toggle button appears on the bottom right of the text box. When hovered the tooltip says "Toggle hard wrap on commit".

[image: Screenshot]

My question is simply:

1. What does this mean (and do)?
2. Why does it appear only after there's more than 1 line in the comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It forces each line of the commit message to by not longer than 72 characters (as [discussed here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/git-commit-message-formating-to-72-characters/16189)).

That will enforce a commit format convention (previously done by [`autoflow`](https://github.com/atom/autoflow)).

Comment: Thanks. I previously thought commit comments are stored in two fields (title and detailed message). After some searching realised title is simply first line of the commit message. My second question seems self explanatory now lol